# Would a scope from an air gun work on a "real" gun?

Tags: hunting, rifles

I am an avid air gun shooter, and have been for many years. I recently got rid of most of my air guns, replacing all but one with the Umarex Hämmerli CR 20s. The CR 20s comes with a Walther 3-9x40 scope.

Living in Norway, there are some significant restrictions on firearm ownership, but one of the ways to get around that, is to be a licensed hunter. I will take the requisite course and exam this coming spring, and will be acquiring a rifle after that.

The rifle I am currently looking at is the Tikka T3 Lite .308 (Links version, though I don't suppose that should make any real difference).

I assume it would likely be a bad idea for me to use the scope off the Hämmerli on the Tikka (though I don't know that it would). What I am wondering is why (or if not, why not).

Comment: I doubt the scope for the Hammerli will be set up to withstand the recoil coming from the .308 so there could be issues with keeping it sighted.

Comment: The scope is unlikely to be fit for a .308, but would probably work for a .22 or similar.

Answer (score 6):

Adjustable power scopes are inherently less sturdy than fixed power scopes because they have more moving parts. A .308 has a fair amount of recoil and after repeatedly firing it could shake loose parts in a scope not designed for that purpose. It all depends on the scope, but an airgun scope would likely fail after a while if mounted on a .308.

Answer (score 3):

The issue isn't really variable vs. fixed power - it's whether the scope in question ("Weaver 3-9x40" is probably at least a dozen different scopes) is suitable for a high-power rifle or not.

Most rimfire (and probably air-rifle) scopes are going to have a 30mm or smaller objective; I'd venture to guess that with a 40mm objective, it will be fine on a .308 .   A quick email to Weaver support (with your scope model) likely will get you a real answer (as well as advice on what mounts you'll need.)

Happy shooting!